# 64 bit on Dell Precision M6600 hangs on reboot and shut down

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, dell, shutdown

I am new to Ubuntu and I discovered that I can't shut down (then black screen with some lines of text shows) and reboot (then the purple screen with dots appear). I need to hold the power button in order to turn it off. What is causing this? Should I install the 32 bit version instead?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug for both 11.10 and 12.04 on the Dell [M6600 laptaps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/841264)

Summary:

Modify `/etc/default/grub` to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="reboot=pci"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` - After another reboot you should be good to go.