# Computer locks up on "last screen" when restarting/shutting down Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, reboot

Every time I restart or shut down my new installation of Ubuntu 12.04, I get to a black screen and the computer just hangs there forever. The only way to get past that is through the physical restart/shutdown button. When I do restart the machine that way, next time Ubuntu starts, there's no indication that a faulty shutdown occurred, everything proceeds as intended.

I would love to investigate this issue and figure out what's going on, since not being able to restart the machine remotely is a show stopper.

Are there any logs I could look into to understand this better? Any other advice?

Edit:

Link to the [Q87M-E motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Q87ME/#specifications), in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen faulty bios cause similar issues.

**What is the make/model of the computer?**

[Similar question with answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125254/64-bit-on-dell-precision-m6600-hangs-on-reboot-and-shut-down)

Eventually in the case for the M6600 from Dell, Dell release a bios update the corrected the issue.  But the grub switch workaround mentioned in the above link may fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll investigate and let you know! Updated the OP with the link to the motherboard in case that helps.

Comment: I did try both reboot=bios and reboot=pci in the grub config and neither seem to have done the trick.